# Meteor App WhiteScreen when coming from Background

Tags: ios, cordova, meteor

I've seen other people with white screen issues once the iOS app loads. My issue is that the App white screens after being in the background for more than 9 plus minutes. Its a quick flash, maybe 1-2 secs, but its annoying and I would like to get rid of it. Any help or work around wold be great. I've already tried the mgd:reload-on-resume package and it hasn't helped at all.

Comment: You need to provide more details. Like error logs.

Answer (score 0):

When an iOS app goes to the background and isn't running background execution code, it can enter into a suspended state.  After that, it can get completely purged from memory and must reload.  I'm not sure about returning from the suspended state, but when reloading after a purge the app will show its splash screen (if it has one) until it has been loaded back into memory.

There's not enough information in your question to diagnose what's happening, but my first step would be to find out whether or not you have a splash screen configured for your app.  My poorly informed guess is that you're seeing an empty splash screen for a couple of seconds while the app reloads.